# independently-sized text columns in CSS?

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns

I wanted to create a text-based page using just HTML and CSS, the point is that there should be two columns, the first 2/3 of the width (as it will be filled by the important text) and the later one 1/3 of the remaining width, just to add details and so,

ive been fidgeting with this code:

```css
.position-trbl-0 {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}  


.overflow-hidden {
   overflow: hidden;
}

.row {
  display: flex;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.col {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col-inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 30px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

  .overflow-auto {
    overflow: auto;
  }
```

```html
<div class="w-100 position-fixed position-trbl-0">
  <div class="container-fluid position-relative position-trbl-0 overflow-hidden h-100">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="col-inner">
          <p class="p-4">
          Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem voluptates suscipit vero perferendis, odio officiis doloribus quae voluptatum debitis sint reiciendis, expedita, saepe eligendi esse numquam! Odio aperiam quidem delectus?
          Enim repellendus nemo dolorum culpa accusantium? At ab laborum harum quasi sunt impedit labore ullam. Saepe ut dolorum omnis, corrupti eveniet atque, illum nulla quia soluta error officiis consequuntur inventore!
          Cupiditate, ipsum consectetur labore beatae quia adipisci dignissimos illum molestias, sed facere temporibus sint sit et neque. Animi dolores nemo pariatur dolor delectus assumenda temporibus, ratione dignissimos rem cum voluptas.
          Libero aliquid laborum doloremque fuga impedit? Consequatur fuga ea, illo dolores sunt maiores laboriosam blanditiis, numquam quod dicta veniam sequi minima, vitae at! Accusantium maxime animi, iusto a impedit rem.
          Necessitatibus ipsam accusantium esse quasi labore, modi veritatis! Dolorum corrupti quisquam fugit unde. Consequatur impedit a totam cum nulla deleniti at atque commodi et repellat! Exercitationem quisquam ducimus itaque accusantium?
          Neque voluptate id quisquam deleniti voluptas distinctio veniam quasi ipsum nam, vitae, ipsa nihil. Voluptas quisquam vel eligendi consequuntur sit rerum rem a magni, dolorem quod cumque? Accusantium, neque assumenda!
          Tempore dignissimos corporis, ratione nihil qui quod itaque facilis laudantium quasi impedit cumque facere ex debitis distinctio ab ipsa beatae enim ut libero. Voluptatum quibusdam soluta quo, voluptatem at a.
          Natus explicabo alias, non vel veniam similique soluta enim porro corporis ea deleniti ipsam consectetur debitis inventore laboriosam omnis nihil labore, placeat eligendi? Excepturi quod in sit aut aliquid assumenda.
          Architecto assumenda officiis nostrum beatae nam aliquam quisquam tenetur aut. Ipsa earum excepturi, beatae incidunt vero nostrum accusantium. Quam officiis facere eos consectetur fugiat fugit minima, et necessitatibus consequuntur dicta.
          Illo modi asperiores incidunt porro voluptates eaque repellendus quis sunt quae nam adipisci, officiis corporis quo dignissimos minus, deserunt amet, nihil fugiat recusandae quibusdam doloribus expedita! Cumque expedita ullam consequatur.
          Reprehenderit aperiam, aut nisi ipsa aliquid ipsum hic facilis! Cupiditate, quidem soluta. Facilis rerum, fugit illum laudantium, labore minima corrupti molestiae doloremque corporis itaque animi ullam reprehenderit odio iure? In.
          Vero at delectus neque cumque totam, laboriosam ipsa temporibus id voluptates officia aliquam! Nulla, adipisci minima quisquam perferendis incidunt dolorem ab? Reiciendis dolorum expedita iusto! Consequuntur distinctio velit facilis dolorem.
          Voluptatum ipsum necessitatibus eligendi natus possimus autem consectetur tenetur, cumque aspernatur dignissimos, est alias vel numquam, accusantium omnis repudiandae laboriosam fugit ex aliquam corporis molestiae! Earum, nobis! Voluptatibus, distinctio saepe.
          Voluptatem distinctio doloremque autem libero fugit praesentium neque cum? Vero, molestiae? Adipisci a voluptate, consectetur culpa, quos, reprehenderit sequi maiores cupiditate sit voluptatum distinctio obcaecati illo nesciunt. Iusto, reprehenderit eius.
          Cumque vel delectus, tenetur nisi, cupiditate facilis recusandae, optio et voluptatibus voluptas quibusdam accusamus! Cupiditate, asperiores provident necessitatibus ipsa fugit repellendus laborum et dolor possimus fugiat non eaque aut iure.
          Tempore earum possimus accusamus ut cum, ipsa odit velit? Quaerat doloribus quam, perspiciatis facere ullam vel, explicabo, voluptas esse minus nam aliquid nobis laudantium! Rerum eos dolor suscipit ratione aperiam.
          Sed eaque exercitationem at repudiandae sunt quisquam dolor! Eveniet aliquid nam odio, aliquam, similique voluptates dolor quo non voluptatum sed mollitia, nobis ipsum doloremque enim eaque magnam odit laudantium atque.
          Reprehenderit fuga molestiae facere reiciendis, magnam obcaecati itaque consectetur dolorem laborum? Natus distinctio, nemo repudiandae eos quae obcaecati sunt excepturi ut accusamus quam iure quis suscipit ducimus non! Officia, deleniti.
          Libero nihil non voluptatem, dolore mollitia perferendis eligendi distinctio pariatur dolor repellendus quae eveniet sit quos alias voluptatum optio illo porro temporibus deserunt doloremque vitae impedit et aliquam minus. Excepturi?
          Molestiae, aspernatur repudiandae quidem maiores mollitia laborum illum nisi nihil impedit nam doloremque voluptatem. Quo architecto doloribus, nisi non officiis, perferendis, vel ad maiores assumenda debitis quibusdam eligendi modi perspiciatis?
          A dignissimos ullam natus laudantium hic ad, officiis atque maiores magni enim, ea voluptates numquam placeat? Nihil, id odit. Enim, beatae. Odio debitis itaque facere, expedita dicta adipisci possimus nisi.
          Alias at aliquam sunt? Aperiam dolorum possimus ab quis nostrum assumenda velit, dignissimos optio dolor repellendus adipisci perspiciatis nihil eveniet numquam cupiditate sint laborum quisquam, ipsum eum magnam? Ipsum, dignissimos?
          Fugit tempora a sequi enim perferendis minima itaque consequuntur harum explicabo quidem cum, ea officiis totam odit exercitationem temporibus hic iure, quae sunt aspernatur labore nulla earum. Expedita, eaque esse.
          Iusto mollitia, eum rem necessitatibus in architecto sequi dolores maiores labore tempora aliquid optio harum quaerat vel quod recusandae sint aspernatur culpa ab. Nesciunt nemo consequatur adipisci officia pariatur at?
          Est placeat voluptas porro architecto ipsum sit. Id inventore odio quia pariatur laboriosam aliquid totam sunt suscipit, incidunt illum ipsum laudantium quis corporis quaerat, accusantium commodi tempora asperiores, maxime facilis.
          Rerum ducimus consequatur eos amet, consectetur voluptatem. Enim maxime cumque rerum ut sit fugiat temporibus expedita similique, iusto modi provident quisquam nam deleniti velit animi consequuntur repellendus corrupti, blanditiis neque?
          Dolores vero nostrum praesentium adipisci quidem! Ad commodi necessitatibus nam dolorem enim, fuga eaque repudiandae quod ducimus, labore mollitia. Doloribus excepturi vitae quasi optio numquam itaque, exercitationem deleniti esse! Eos?
          Soluta a odio incidunt corrupti illum. Amet possimus fugiat atque qui mollitia eum, reprehenderit aliquid ab ex sequi quos! Sint dolorem provident nihil nemo facere, officiis incidunt. Esse, illo voluptatum!
          Velit atque, fugit ab dolor est dicta necessitatibus obcaecati vero recusandae inventore rerum saepe iure exercitationem numquam neque. Beatae atque necessitatibus nam facilis, qui eos ea a tempore harum nostrum.
          Nulla rerum doloribus pariatur fugit necessitatibus libero explicabo molestias eum excepturi laboriosam quos dolores animi quasi dicta, maxime deserunt! Maiores veritatis cumque illo ad. Libero odio necessitatibus delectus dolorem corporis.
        </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="col-inner">
          <p class="p-4">
          Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem voluptates suscipit vero perferendis, odio officiis doloribus quae voluptatum debitis sint reiciendis, expedita, saepe eligendi esse numquam! Odio aperiam quidem delectus?
          Enim repellendus nemo dolorum culpa accusantium? At ab laborum harum quasi sunt impedit labore ullam. Saepe ut dolorum omnis, corrupti eveniet atque, illum nulla quia soluta error officiis consequuntur inventore!
          Cupiditate, ipsum consectetur labore beatae quia adipisci dignissimos illum molestias, sed facere temporibus sint sit et neque. Animi dolores nemo pariatur dolor delectus assumenda temporibus, ratione dignissimos rem cum voluptas.
          Libero aliquid laborum doloremque fuga impedit? Consequatur fuga ea, illo dolores sunt maiores laboriosam blanditiis, numquam quod dicta veniam sequi minima, vitae at! Accusantium maxime animi, iusto a impedit rem.
          Necessitatibus ipsam accusantium esse quasi labore, modi veritatis! Dolorum corrupti quisquam fugit unde. Consequatur impedit a totam cum nulla deleniti at atque commodi et repellat! Exercitationem quisquam ducimus itaque accusantium?
          Neque voluptate id quisquam deleniti voluptas distinctio veniam quasi ipsum nam, vitae, ipsa nihil. Voluptas quisquam vel eligendi consequuntur sit rerum rem a magni, dolorem quod cumque? Accusantium, neque assumenda!
          Tempore dignissimos corporis, ratione nihil qui quod itaque facilis laudantium quasi impedit cumque facere ex debitis distinctio ab ipsa beatae enim ut libero. Voluptatum quibusdam soluta quo, voluptatem at a.
          Natus explicabo alias, non vel veniam similique soluta enim porro corporis ea deleniti ipsam consectetur debitis inventore laboriosam omnis nihil labore, placeat eligendi? Excepturi quod in sit aut aliquid assumenda.
          Architecto assumenda officiis nostrum beatae nam aliquam quisquam tenetur aut. Ipsa earum excepturi, beatae incidunt vero nostrum accusantium. Quam officiis facere eos consectetur fugiat fugit minima, et necessitatibus consequuntur dicta.
          Illo modi asperiores incidunt porro voluptates eaque repellendus quis sunt quae nam adipisci, officiis corporis quo dignissimos minus, deserunt amet, nihil fugiat recusandae quibusdam doloribus expedita! Cumque expedita ullam consequatur.
          Reprehenderit aperiam, aut nisi ipsa aliquid ipsum hic facilis! Cupiditate, quidem soluta. Facilis rerum, fugit illum laudantium, labore minima corrupti molestiae doloremque corporis itaque animi ullam reprehenderit odio iure? In.
          Vero at delectus neque cumque totam, laboriosam ipsa temporibus id voluptates officia aliquam! Nulla, adipisci minima quisquam perferendis incidunt dolorem ab? Reiciendis dolorum expedita iusto! Consequuntur distinctio velit facilis dolorem.
          Voluptatum ipsum necessitatibus eligendi natus possimus autem consectetur tenetur, cumque aspernatur dignissimos, est alias vel numquam, accusantium omnis repudiandae laboriosam fugit ex aliquam corporis molestiae! Earum, nobis! Voluptatibus, distinctio saepe.
          Voluptatem distinctio doloremque autem libero fugit praesentium neque cum? Vero, molestiae? Adipisci a voluptate, consectetur culpa, quos, reprehenderit sequi maiores cupiditate sit voluptatum distinctio obcaecati illo nesciunt. Iusto, reprehenderit eius.
          Cumque vel delectus, tenetur nisi, cupiditate facilis recusandae, optio et voluptatibus voluptas quibusdam accusamus! Cupiditate, asperiores provident necessitatibus ipsa fugit repellendus laborum et dolor possimus fugiat non eaque aut iure.
          Tempore earum possimus accusamus ut cum, ipsa odit velit? Quaerat doloribus quam, perspiciatis facere ullam vel, explicabo, voluptas esse minus nam aliquid nobis laudantium! Rerum eos dolor suscipit ratione aperiam.
          Sed eaque exercitationem at repudiandae sunt quisquam dolor! Eveniet aliquid nam odio, aliquam, similique voluptates dolor quo non voluptatum sed mollitia, nobis ipsum doloremque enim eaque magnam odit laudantium atque.
          Reprehenderit fuga molestiae facere reiciendis, magnam obcaecati itaque consectetur dolorem laborum? Natus distinctio, nemo repudiandae eos quae obcaecati sunt excepturi ut accusamus quam iure quis suscipit ducimus non! Officia, deleniti.
          Libero nihil non voluptatem, dolore mollitia perferendis eligendi distinctio pariatur dolor repellendus quae eveniet sit quos alias voluptatum optio illo porro temporibus deserunt doloremque vitae impedit et aliquam minus. Excepturi?
          Molestiae, aspernatur repudiandae quidem maiores mollitia laborum illum nisi nihil impedit nam doloremque voluptatem. Quo architecto doloribus, nisi non officiis, perferendis, vel ad maiores assumenda debitis quibusdam eligendi modi perspiciatis?
          A dignissimos ullam natus laudantium hic ad, officiis atque maiores magni enim, ea voluptates numquam placeat? Nihil, id odit. Enim, beatae. Odio debitis itaque facere, expedita dicta adipisci possimus nisi.
          Alias at aliquam sunt? Aperiam dolorum possimus ab quis nostrum assumenda velit, dignissimos optio dolor repellendus adipisci perspiciatis nihil eveniet numquam cupiditate sint laborum quisquam, ipsum eum magnam? Ipsum, dignissimos?
          Fugit tempora a sequi enim perferendis minima itaque consequuntur harum explicabo quidem cum, ea officiis totam odit exercitationem temporibus hic iure, quae sunt aspernatur labore nulla earum. Expedita, eaque esse.
          Iusto mollitia, eum rem necessitatibus in architecto sequi dolores maiores labore tempora aliquid optio harum quaerat vel quod recusandae sint aspernatur culpa ab. Nesciunt nemo consequatur adipisci officia pariatur at?
          Est placeat voluptas porro architecto ipsum sit. Id inventore odio quia pariatur laboriosam aliquid totam sunt suscipit, incidunt illum ipsum laudantium quis corporis quaerat, accusantium commodi tempora asperiores, maxime facilis.
          Rerum ducimus consequatur eos amet, consectetur voluptatem. Enim maxime cumque rerum ut sit fugiat temporibus expedita similique, iusto modi provident quisquam nam deleniti velit animi consequuntur repellendus corrupti, blanditiis neque?
          Dolores vero nostrum praesentium adipisci quidem! Ad commodi necessitatibus nam dolorem enim, fuga eaque repudiandae quod ducimus, labore mollitia. Doloribus excepturi vitae quasi optio numquam itaque, exercitationem deleniti esse! Eos?
          Soluta a odio incidunt corrupti illum. Amet possimus fugiat atque qui mollitia eum, reprehenderit aliquid ab ex sequi quos! Sint dolorem provident nihil nemo facere, officiis incidunt. Esse, illo voluptatum!
          Velit atque, fugit ab dolor est dicta necessitatibus obcaecati vero recusandae inventore rerum saepe iure exercitationem numquam neque. Beatae atque necessitatibus nam facilis, qui eos ea a tempore harum nostrum.
          Nulla rerum doloribus pariatur fugit necessitatibus libero explicabo molestias eum excepturi laboriosam quos dolores animi quasi dicta, maxime deserunt! Maiores veritatis cumque illo ad. Libero odio necessitatibus delectus dolorem corporis.
        </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

but can't seem to find it!

Comment: col-8 and col-4 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a `grid` solution, and the `:nth-child()` pseudo-class for the `col` class.

The first column is `2/3` and the second is `1/3`.

```css
.position-trbl-0 {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}  


.overflow-hidden {
   overflow: hidden;
}

.row {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.col {
  height: 100%;
  padding: 0 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.col:nth-child(1) {
  grid-column: 1 / span 2;
}

.col-inner {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0 30px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  box-sizing: content-box;
}

  .overflow-auto {
    overflow: auto;
  }
```

```html
<div class="w-100 position-fixed position-trbl-0">
  <div class="container-fluid position-relative position-trbl-0 overflow-hidden h-100">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div class="col-inner">
          <p class="p-4">
          Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem voluptates suscipit vero perferendis, odio officiis doloribus quae voluptatum debitis sint reiciendis, expedita, saepe eligendi esse numquam! Odio aperiam quidem delectus?
          Enim repellendus nemo dolorum culpa accusantium? At ab laborum harum quasi sunt impedit labore ullam. Saepe ut dolorum omnis, corrupti eveniet atque, illum nulla quia soluta error officiis consequuntur inventore!
          Cupiditate, ipsum consectetur labore beatae quia adipisci dignissimos illum molestias, sed facere temporibus sint sit et neque. Animi dolores nemo pariatur dolor delectus assumenda temporibus, ratione dignissimos rem cum voluptas.
          Libero aliquid laborum doloremque fuga impedit? Consequatur fuga ea, illo dolores sunt maiores laboriosam blanditiis, numquam quod dicta veniam sequi minima, vitae at! Accusantium maxime animi, iusto a impedit rem.
          Necessitatibus ipsam accusantium esse quasi labore, modi veritatis! Dolorum corrupti quisquam fugit unde. Consequatur impedit a totam cum nulla deleniti at atque commodi et repellat! Exercitationem quisquam ducimus itaque accusantium?
          Neque voluptate id quisquam deleniti voluptas distinctio veniam quasi ipsum nam, vitae, ipsa nihil. Voluptas quisquam vel eligendi consequuntur sit rerum rem a magni, dolorem quod cumque? Accusantium, neque assumenda!
          Tempore dignissimos corporis, ratione nihil qui quod itaque facilis laudantium quasi impedit cumque facere ex debitis distinctio ab ipsa beatae enim ut libero. Voluptatum quibusdam soluta quo, voluptatem at a.
          Natus explicabo alias, non vel veniam similique soluta enim porro corporis ea deleniti ipsam consectetur debitis inventore laboriosam omnis nihil labore, placeat eligendi? Excepturi quod in sit aut aliquid assumenda.
          Architecto assumenda officiis nostrum beatae nam aliquam quisquam tenetur aut. Ipsa earum excepturi, beatae incidunt vero nostrum accusantium. Quam officiis facere eos consectetur fugiat fugit minima, et necessitatibus consequuntur dicta.
          Illo modi asperiores incidunt porro voluptates eaque repellendus quis sunt quae nam adipisci, officiis corporis quo dignissimos minus, deserunt amet, nihil fugiat recusandae quibusdam doloribus expedita! Cumque expedita ullam consequatur.
          Reprehenderit aperiam, aut nisi ipsa aliquid ipsum hic facilis! Cupiditate, quidem soluta. Facilis rerum, fugit illum laudantium, labore minima corrupti molestiae doloremque corporis itaque animi ullam reprehenderit odio iure? In.
          Vero at delectus neque cumque totam, laboriosam ipsa temporibus id voluptates officia aliquam! Nulla, adipisci minima quisquam perferendis incidunt dolorem ab? Reiciendis dolorum expedita iusto! Consequuntur distinctio velit facilis dolorem.
          Voluptatum ipsum necessitatibus eligendi natus possimus autem consectetur tenetur, cumque aspernatur dignissimos, est alias vel numquam, accusantium omnis repudiandae laboriosam fugit ex aliquam corporis molestiae! Earum, nobis! Voluptatibus, distinctio saepe.
          Voluptatem distinctio doloremque autem libero fugit praesentium neque cum? Vero, molestiae? Adipisci a voluptate, consectetur culpa, quos, reprehenderit sequi maiores cupiditate sit voluptatum distinctio obcaecati illo nesciunt. Iusto, reprehenderit eius.
          Cumque vel delectus, tenetur nisi, cupiditate facilis recusandae, optio et voluptatibus voluptas quibusdam accusamus! Cupiditate, asperiores provident necessitatibus ipsa fugit repellendus laborum et dolor possimus fugiat non eaque aut iure.
          Tempore earum possimus accusamus ut cum, ipsa odit velit? Quaerat doloribus quam, perspiciatis facere ullam vel, explicabo, voluptas esse minus nam aliquid nobis laudantium! Rerum eos dolor suscipit ratione aperiam.
          Sed eaque exercitationem at repudiandae sunt quisquam dolor! Eveniet aliquid nam odio, aliquam, similique voluptates dolor quo non voluptatum sed mollitia, nobis ipsum doloremque enim eaque magnam odit laudantium atque.
          Reprehenderit fuga molestiae facere reiciendis, magnam obcaecati itaque consectetur dolorem laborum? Natus distinctio, nemo repudiandae eos quae obcaecati sunt excepturi ut accusamus quam iure quis suscipit ducimus non! Officia, deleniti.
          Libero nihil non voluptatem, dolore mollitia perferendis eligendi distinctio pariatur dolor repellendus quae eveniet sit quos alias voluptatum optio illo porro temporibus deserunt doloremque vitae impedit et aliquam minus. Excepturi?
          Molestiae, aspernatur repudiandae quidem maiores mollitia laborum illum nisi nihil impedit nam doloremque voluptatem. Quo architecto doloribus, nisi non officiis, perferendis, vel ad maiores assumenda debitis quibusdam eligendi modi perspiciatis?
          A dignissimos ullam natus laudantium hic ad, officiis atque maiores magni enim, ea voluptates numquam placeat? Nihil, id odit. Enim, beatae. Odio debitis itaque facere, expedita dicta adipisci possimus nisi.
          Alias at aliquam sunt? Aperiam dolorum possimus ab quis nostrum assumenda velit, dignissimos optio dolor repellendus adipisci perspiciatis nihil eveniet numquam cupiditate sint laborum quisquam, ipsum eum magnam? Ipsum, dignissimos?
          Fugit tempora a sequi enim perferendis minima itaque consequuntur harum explicabo quidem cum, ea officiis totam odit exercitationem temporibus hic iure, quae sunt aspernatur labore nulla earum. Expedita, eaque esse.
          Iusto mollitia, eum rem necessitatibus in architecto sequi dolores maiores labore tempora aliquid optio harum quaerat vel quod recusandae sint aspernatur culpa ab. Nesciunt nemo consequatur adipisci officia pariatur at?
          Est placeat voluptas porro architecto ipsum sit. Id inventore odio quia pariatur laboriosam aliquid totam sunt suscipit, incidunt illum ipsum laudantium quis corporis quaerat, accusantium commodi tempora asperiores, maxime facilis.
          Rerum ducimus consequatur eos amet, consectetur voluptatem. Enim maxime cumque rerum ut sit fugiat temporibus expedita similique, iusto modi provident quisquam nam deleniti velit animi consequuntur repellendus corrupti, blanditiis neque?
          Dolores vero nostrum praesentium adipisci quidem! Ad commodi necessitatibus nam dolorem enim, fuga eaque repudiandae quod ducimus, labore mollitia. Doloribus excepturi vitae quasi optio numquam itaque, exercitationem deleniti esse! Eos?
          Soluta a odio incidunt corrupti illum. Amet possimus fugiat atque qui mollitia eum, reprehenderit aliquid ab ex sequi quos! Sint dolorem provident nihil nemo facere, officiis incidunt. Esse, illo voluptatum!
          Velit atque, fugit ab dolor est dicta necessitatibus obcaecati vero recusandae inventore rerum saepe iure exercitationem numquam neque. Beatae atque necessitatibus nam facilis, qui eos ea a tempore harum nostrum.
          Nulla rerum doloribus pariatur fugit necessitatibus libero explicabo molestias eum excepturi laboriosam quos dolores animi quasi dicta, maxime deserunt! Maiores veritatis cumque illo ad. Libero odio necessitatibus delectus dolorem corporis.
        </p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col">
        <div class="col-inner">
          <p class="p-4">
          Lorem, ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Rem voluptates suscipit vero perferendis, odio officiis doloribus quae voluptatum debitis sint reiciendis, expedita, saepe eligendi esse numquam! Odio aperiam quidem delectus?
          Enim repellendus nemo dolorum culpa accusantium? At ab laborum harum quasi sunt impedit labore ullam. Saepe ut dolorum omnis, corrupti eveniet atque, illum nulla quia soluta error officiis consequuntur inventore!
          Cupiditate, ipsum consectetur labore beatae quia adipisci dignissimos illum molestias, sed facere temporibus sint sit et neque. Animi dolores nemo pariatur dolor delectus assumenda temporibus, ratione dignissimos rem cum voluptas.
          Libero aliquid laborum doloremque fuga impedit? Consequatur fuga ea, illo dolores sunt maiores laboriosam blanditiis, numquam quod dicta veniam sequi minima, vitae at! Accusantium maxime animi, iusto a impedit rem.
          Necessitatibus ipsam accusantium esse quasi labore, modi veritatis! Dolorum corrupti quisquam fugit unde. Consequatur impedit a totam cum nulla deleniti at atque commodi et repellat! Exercitationem quisquam ducimus itaque accusantium?
          Neque voluptate id quisquam deleniti voluptas distinctio veniam quasi ipsum nam, vitae, ipsa nihil. Voluptas quisquam vel eligendi consequuntur sit rerum rem a magni, dolorem quod cumque? Accusantium, neque assumenda!
          Tempore dignissimos corporis, ratione nihil qui quod itaque facilis laudantium quasi impedit cumque facere ex debitis distinctio ab ipsa beatae enim ut libero. Voluptatum quibusdam soluta quo, voluptatem at a.
          Natus explicabo alias, non vel veniam similique soluta enim porro corporis ea deleniti ipsam consectetur debitis inventore laboriosam omnis nihil labore, placeat eligendi? Excepturi quod in sit aut aliquid assumenda.
          Architecto assumenda officiis nostrum beatae nam aliquam quisquam tenetur aut. Ipsa earum excepturi, beatae incidunt vero nostrum accusantium. Quam officiis facere eos consectetur fugiat fugit minima, et necessitatibus consequuntur dicta.
          Illo modi asperiores incidunt porro voluptates eaque repellendus quis sunt quae nam adipisci, officiis corporis quo dignissimos minus, deserunt amet, nihil fugiat recusandae quibusdam doloribus expedita! Cumque expedita ullam consequatur.
          Reprehenderit aperiam, aut nisi ipsa aliquid ipsum hic facilis! Cupiditate, quidem soluta. Facilis rerum, fugit illum laudantium, labore minima corrupti molestiae doloremque corporis itaque animi ullam reprehenderit odio iure? In.
          Vero at delectus neque cumque totam, laboriosam ipsa temporibus id voluptates officia aliquam! Nulla, adipisci minima quisquam perferendis incidunt dolorem ab? Reiciendis dolorum expedita iusto! Consequuntur distinctio velit facilis dolorem.
          Voluptatum ipsum necessitatibus eligendi natus possimus autem consectetur tenetur, cumque aspernatur dignissimos, est alias vel numquam, accusantium omnis repudiandae laboriosam fugit ex aliquam corporis molestiae! Earum, nobis! Voluptatibus, distinctio saepe.
          Voluptatem distinctio doloremque autem libero fugit praesentium neque cum? Vero, molestiae? Adipisci a voluptate, consectetur culpa, quos, reprehenderit sequi maiores cupiditate sit voluptatum distinctio obcaecati illo nesciunt. Iusto, reprehenderit eius.
          Cumque vel delectus, tenetur nisi, cupiditate facilis recusandae, optio et voluptatibus voluptas quibusdam accusamus! Cupiditate, asperiores provident necessitatibus ipsa fugit repellendus laborum et dolor possimus fugiat non eaque aut iure.
          Tempore earum possimus accusamus ut cum, ipsa odit velit? Quaerat doloribus quam, perspiciatis facere ullam vel, explicabo, voluptas esse minus nam aliquid nobis laudantium! Rerum eos dolor suscipit ratione aperiam.
          Sed eaque exercitationem at repudiandae sunt quisquam dolor! Eveniet aliquid nam odio, aliquam, similique voluptates dolor quo non voluptatum sed mollitia, nobis ipsum doloremque enim eaque magnam odit laudantium atque.
          Reprehenderit fuga molestiae facere reiciendis, magnam obcaecati itaque consectetur dolorem laborum? Natus distinctio, nemo repudiandae eos quae obcaecati sunt excepturi ut accusamus quam iure quis suscipit ducimus non! Officia, deleniti.
          Libero nihil non voluptatem, dolore mollitia perferendis eligendi distinctio pariatur dolor repellendus quae eveniet sit quos alias voluptatum optio illo porro temporibus deserunt doloremque vitae impedit et aliquam minus. Excepturi?
          Molestiae, aspernatur repudiandae quidem maiores mollitia laborum illum nisi nihil impedit nam doloremque voluptatem. Quo architecto doloribus, nisi non officiis, perferendis, vel ad maiores assumenda debitis quibusdam eligendi modi perspiciatis?
          A dignissimos ullam natus laudantium hic ad, officiis atque maiores magni enim, ea voluptates numquam placeat? Nihil, id odit. Enim, beatae. Odio debitis itaque facere, expedita dicta adipisci possimus nisi.
          Alias at aliquam sunt? Aperiam dolorum possimus ab quis nostrum assumenda velit, dignissimos optio dolor repellendus adipisci perspiciatis nihil eveniet numquam cupiditate sint laborum quisquam, ipsum eum magnam? Ipsum, dignissimos?
          Fugit tempora a sequi enim perferendis minima itaque consequuntur harum explicabo quidem cum, ea officiis totam odit exercitationem temporibus hic iure, quae sunt aspernatur labore nulla earum. Expedita, eaque esse.
          Iusto mollitia, eum rem necessitatibus in architecto sequi dolores maiores labore tempora aliquid optio harum quaerat vel quod recusandae sint aspernatur culpa ab. Nesciunt nemo consequatur adipisci officia pariatur at?
          Est placeat voluptas porro architecto ipsum sit. Id inventore odio quia pariatur laboriosam aliquid totam sunt suscipit, incidunt illum ipsum laudantium quis corporis quaerat, accusantium commodi tempora asperiores, maxime facilis.
          Rerum ducimus consequatur eos amet, consectetur voluptatem. Enim maxime cumque rerum ut sit fugiat temporibus expedita similique, iusto modi provident quisquam nam deleniti velit animi consequuntur repellendus corrupti, blanditiis neque?
          Dolores vero nostrum praesentium adipisci quidem! Ad commodi necessitatibus nam dolorem enim, fuga eaque repudiandae quod ducimus, labore mollitia. Doloribus excepturi vitae quasi optio numquam itaque, exercitationem deleniti esse! Eos?
          Soluta a odio incidunt corrupti illum. Amet possimus fugiat atque qui mollitia eum, reprehenderit aliquid ab ex sequi quos! Sint dolorem provident nihil nemo facere, officiis incidunt. Esse, illo voluptatum!
          Velit atque, fugit ab dolor est dicta necessitatibus obcaecati vero recusandae inventore rerum saepe iure exercitationem numquam neque. Beatae atque necessitatibus nam facilis, qui eos ea a tempore harum nostrum.
          Nulla rerum doloribus pariatur fugit necessitatibus libero explicabo molestias eum excepturi laboriosam quos dolores animi quasi dicta, maxime deserunt! Maiores veritatis cumque illo ad. Libero odio necessitatibus delectus dolorem corporis.
        </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```